# Timelines with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm working on a timeline app using `DataGrid` control but I can't find a way to insert and bind a `Canvas` control in the cells. Should I use another control?

[image]

```
<UserControl x:Class="Timelines.Controls.TimelineViewer2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Timelines.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="TimelineGrids" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Timeline" CanUserResize="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas Name="TimelineCanvas"></Canvas>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: what is the problem here? do you mean you can't put `Canvas` at the right position in a `DataGrid` cell? Show the code to help explain the problem please.

Comment: I added my current sample code. For now, I want to add rows and get access to each 'Canvas' to draw the timelines.

Comment: But you would like to do these from code behind and you got problem with accessing the canvas, that is your problem?

Comment: @Kaspar: Yes, that is my problem, but as kennyzx says, it seems to be difficult or maybe impossible to access a control inside a `DataGrid` cell.

Comment: @carlos, it is possible, to access the `Canvas` from code behind, see [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-find-datatemplate-generated-elements), but then you have other problems, that is why I don't recommend that way.

Comment: I agree, it is possible and you will be able to do these from code begind usint what @kennyzx provided, but it is better to use data-binding in my opinion as well.

Comment: Got it. I'll try **UserControl** with **Data bining**. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to draw the timelines.

**Data binding vs. code behind**

The first is using **data binding**, which you are already on half-way; In this way, you define the data model and the data template, an entry in the model may have properties like **Name**, **Born** and **Married**, and **Born** and **Married** has an integer value like 1980 to indicate the year, and the ***data template*** defines how an entry is visually rendered.

The other approach is using code behind, constructing a `Canvas` and drawing the lines, labels on the `Canvas`... using C#, and then insert the `Canvas` to a `DataGrid` cell.

**Problem:**

And now you get stuck, because you are hoping to mix them, first use data binding to populate some rows in the `DataGrid` from the data model, each row has a `Name` label and a `Canvas`, then you want to access the `Canvas` for drawing using code behind. Since the `Canvas` is created using data binding, you have difficulty to get a reference to it, you can't even access it with the name `TimelineCanvas`, since that name has a 'template scope' - meaning it is only accessible from within the template.

It is possible, to access the Canvas from code behind, using a **VisualTreeHelper**. See How to: [Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-find-datatemplate-generated-elements). But I don't recommend this "mixed approach".

**Solution**

Stick to either data binding (if you are comfortable with XAML) or code behind.

If you choose data binding, add the lines and labels *insides* the `DataTemplate`, of course you need to calculate their position on the Canvas - by binding to some properties in the model.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Canvas Name="TimelineCanvas">
            <Label Content="Born" Canvas.X="30" Canvas.Y="20" />
            <Line
                X1="10" Y1="30"
                X2="350" Y2="30"
                Stroke="Blue"
                StrokeThickness="1" />
            <!--The whole data template can be quite complicated, but here I just hard code a label and a line to get you started-->
        </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

If you choose code behind, remove the `CellTemplate`.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Canvas Name="TimelineCanvas"></Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Both approaches are quite challenging in my opinion, you may define a **UserControl** for a `Timeline`, so the construction logic can be isolated in one separated class.

Comment: In the case of a **User Control** for `Timeline`, how am I supposed to initialize or add events from the code behind?

Comment: You define a user control, you get two files auto generated...It is much the same way you do in the `MainPage.xaml` and `MainPage.XAML.cs`, initialize in the constructor, add events in XAML...